# How to add value from list into dictionary?

Tags: python

```
dict={}
i=["abc","def","ghi","jkl"]
j=[["a","b","c","d"],["q","w","e","r"],["t","y","u","i"]]
for item in i:
    dict[item]=[str(j[item])]
print dict
```

Output should be like

```
dict={"abc":["a","b","c","d"], "def":["q","w","e","r"] ...}
```

How can I add list into dictionary in python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`zip()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to combine the two lists:

```
dict(zip(i, j))
```

Demo:

```
>>> i=["abc","def","ghi","jkl"]
>>> j=[["a","b","c","d"],["q","w","e","r"],["t","y","u","i"]]
>>> dict(zip(i, j))
{'abc': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'ghi': ['t', 'y', 'u', 'i'], 'def': ['q', 'w', 'e', 'r']}
```

`zip()` pairs up elements from lists into a sequence of tuples; the `dict()` constructor takes a sequence of tuples and interprets them as key-value pairs.

Comment: How to call it inside the program? so that I can use it for further steps..?

Comment: Store the result of the `dict(zip(i, j))` call in a variable? It returns a normal, regular python dictionary.

Comment: line1=['Pin', 'Type', 'Description']  line2=[["abb","def","ggt"],["ffr","uyt","uuu"]] how to get output like {"pin":["abb","ffr"],"type" :"dfe","uyt"]... so on...?

Comment: @ApoorvaShankar: exactly the same way; `dict(zip(line1, line2))`. Your keys come from `line1`, your values from `line2`, so you want to pair up items from `line1` with corresponding items from `line2`, in that order.

Comment: No I didnt get, Pin should take first element from list, i.e, abb and ffr...?

Comment: `zip(line1, line2)` produces `[(line1[0], line2[0]), (line1[1], line2[1]), (line1[2], line2[2]), etc.]`. `dict()` takes those pairs interpreting them as key and value, so `(line1[0], line2[0])` becomes `{line1[0]: line2[0]}`, etc.

Comment: if i have like this then..? line1=[["pin","type"]["next","something"]] ?

Comment: @ApoorvaShankar: Why not try these scenarios out in a interactive interpreter? Build lists, combine them with `zip()` and see what happens..